# Fedora 15 Gnome Shell Pauses on certain wireless networks

Tags: wifi, gnome-shell

Whenever I connect to my girlfriend's wireless network, gnome shell will "pause" randomly. Gnome shell quits updating or drawing. The clock is set to use seconds, and will pause for anywhere from 1 to 15 seconds (no render updates, then suddenly jumps). X seems to still be running- when these pauses happen, any text I type will appear when gnome is unpaused and the mouse cursor is very responsive. During these pauses, I can also switch to a different terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and work normally. This does not happen on any other wireless networks. I have not tested connecting to the AP over ethernet. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

AP is a Verizon licensed Actiontec MI424-WR Rev.D

```
[~]$ lspci | grep -i net
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
[~]$ lspci -vv -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 52
    Region 0: Memory at ded00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
[~]$ modinfo iwlwifi (http://pastie.org/3455752)
```

[Edit]

```
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
109 packets transmitted, 107 received, 1% packet loss, time 108140ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.817/5.932/96.705/14.555 ms
```

No noticeable changes in ping times during a "pause" event.

[Edit 2]

Nothing in dmesg or /var/log/messages

[Edit 3, answers for Kaptk2]

WEP encryption, AP does DHCP, I am assuming Wireless N because the AP and card are both modern, but cannot confirm that.

PS How do I confirm that? `iw dev wlan0 station dump` does not have the needed info.

[Edit 4, more on the AP]

```
[~]$ iw wifi0 scan ssid VL440
BSS 00:1f:90:e2:73:17 (on wlan0) -- associated
    TSF: 198981120700 usec (2d, 07:16:21)
    freq: 2462
    beacon interval: 100
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0531)
    signal: -41.00 dBm
    last seen: 99 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: VL440
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0 
    DS Parameter set: channel 11
    Country: US     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
            Channels [1 - 11] @ 27 dBm
    Power constraint: 0 dB
    ERP: <no flags>
    Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 
    WMM:     * Parameter version 1
             * u-APSD
             * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
             * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
             * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
             * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
```

Comment: Is their any encryption running? Are you connecting via N or B/G. What does top show?

Answer (score -1):

Are you absolutly shure it is the WLAN?

Maybe you ran on battery there, or stream a lot to your HD, maybe it's the sync to the HD.

Comment: This occurred both on battery and when plugged in; both at full power and charging. There was no HD streaming; basic browsing (google, stack overflow, etc) and browsing with Pandora running.

Side note: We broke up a couple months ago, so haven't been able to work on it since.

Comment: @DavidSouther If your question is no longer applicable, feel free to close it. Otherwise it will continue showing up for people to attempt to answer.